# CouchDB URL Rewriting for SEO

Tags: ajax, seo, couchdb, hashbang

I'm trying to create an entire site hosted purely on CouchDB (no nginx reverse proxy either) using a lot of client side Jquery/AJAX magic. Now I'm in the process of making it SEO friendly. I'm using vhosts and URL rewrites to route traffic from the root to my index.html file:

vhost:

`example.com /dbname/_design/dd/_rewrite/`

In my rewrite definition:

```
rewrites:[
   {
       "from": "/db/*",
       "to": "/../../../*",
       "query": {
       }
   },
   {
       "from": "/",
       "to": "../../static/index.html",
       "query": {
       }
   }
]
```

[When optimizing a site for SEO, Google requires you to do a few things](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started):

- Use the hashbang (#!) in your friendly URL to tell the web crawler that you are an AJAX site with web crawlable material: `http://example.com/index.html#!home`
- Use an http query argument to provide an HTML escaped fragment of that AJAX page: `http://example.com/index.html?_escaped_fragment=home`

I tried the following with no luck:

```
rewrites:[
   {
       "from": "/db/*",
       "to": "/../../../*",
       "query": {
       }
   },
   {
       "from": "/",
       "to": "../../static/index.html",
       "query": {
       }
   }, /* FIRST ATTEMPT */
      {
       "from": "/?_escaped_fragment=:_escaped_fragment",
       "to": "/_show/escaped_fragment/:_escaped_fragment",
       "query": {
       }
   }, /* SECOND ATTEMPT */
      {
       "from": "/?_escaped_fragment=*",
       "to": "/_show/escaped_fragment/*",
       "query": {
       }
   }, /* THIRD ATTEMPT */
      {
       "from": "/",
       "to": "/_show/escaped_fragment/:_escaped_fragment",
       "query": {
       }
   }
]
```

From what I've seen, CouchDB's URL rewriter is not capable of distinguishing the difference between a URLs with args and no args. Has anyone had luck creating such a rule with CouchDB URL rewrites?

Comment: Your third attempt is the only correct. Just query `/_design/ddoc/_rewrite?_escaped_fragment=foo` and it will be rewritten to `/_design/ddoc/_show/escaped_fragment/foo`. Sure, you need to have `escaped_fragment` show function defined in this case.

Comment: @Kxepal The only problem with the 3rd option is that CouchDB treats it the same as my rewrite rule for sending "/" to "../../static/index.html".

Comment: yea, collision. May be merge them? In this case the `:_escaped_fragment` will be `undefined` (`_rewrite/` -> `_show/escaped_fragment/undefined`), but you'll note that he is missed in query object, so it should be easy to make another redirect from show function to `static/index.html` (not nice, but still solution)

Comment: I've thought about using redirects, but the Google specification says that it must be the exact same URL for the website to be crawl-able: `http://example.com/index.html#!home` & `http://example.com/index.html?_escaped_fragment=home`. If I redirect to somewhere different than `http://example.com/index.html`, I will end up with a new URL (chasing my tail).

Comment: BTW, I may not be able to find a solution to this problem, but I found a potential alternative to the hashbang/escaped_fragment method of SEO: http://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a answer to the question, but I've developed a solution for the bigger problem of making crawlable sites hosted on CouchDB. It is a system that makes use of [Facebook's React](http://facebook.github.io/react/), *list* and *show* functions, ajax on the client and `window.history` to render the same HTML components filled with data at CouchDB and at the browser:

https://github.com/fiatjaf/reactive-couch

This solution doesn't need the hashbang, because for each unique URL the browser navigates to, using ajax and `window.history` or simple links (be it `_list/listName/viewName`/`_show/displayKind/c305ee4d-8611-4e08-b9d3-3318835632a9` or something rewritten as `/name`/`/kind/c305ee4d-8611-4e08-b9d3-3318835632a9`), the server can render the pertinent content.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've developed a similar approach using pure client side Javascript. I use it on my personal blog: http://pokstad.com

Basically, I render the page in the browser, and then I capture the entire document, serialize it, and save it as an attachment. This attachment gets returned when users/crawlers browse directly to a link. Otherwise, I use HTML5 history api to load/unload AJAX pages.